# How to convert form of communication from Java to Python

Tags: java, python

Good afternoon,

I have a Java scrip that performs communication between the Java application and the MIO Commbox controller.

My question is how to convert this Java script to Python, in short, I need to perform the communication via python.

Follow the Script in JAVA:

```
URLConnection connection =  new URL("http://192.168.0.8:4091/multiio").openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

try(OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) { 
    output.write("{\"event\": \"read_inputs_outputs\", \"ip\" : \"192.168.0.100\", \"port\" : \"4091\", \"data\" : []}".getBytes("UTF-8"));
}         

BufferedReader response = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

String text = "";
String json = "";
while((text = response.readLine()) != null){
    json += text;
}
```

I need to write this same code in Python, I started the encoding as below, but I am not having the answer

Initial condition in Python

```
import socket

sockt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sockt.connect(('192.168.0.8', 4091))
print("Conectado...")

data = bytearray()
payload = '{\"event\":\"read_inputs_outputs\",\"ip\":\"192.168.0.100\",\"port\":\"4091\",\"data\":\"[]\"}'
data = payload.encode('utf-8')

sockt.send(data)

resposta = sockt.recv(4091)
print(resposta)
```

I just printed on the "Connected ..." console and nothing else appears on the console, no errors.

Can anyone tell me what to do? Thank you!

Comment: Hit the same URL as the Java code?  It looks like you're just opening a socket directly on port 4091.

Comment: It looks like the device responds to HTTPS requests formatted as JSON, is that correct? If so why not use the `requests` and `json` modules to abstract away the direct socket connections and json encoding?

Comment: yes, the answer is a JSON. Alex how to use json requestse modules to abstract socket connections

Comment: Take a look at the the [Quickstart Guide for Requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)